# Finding max at some specific intervals in a single column in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, while-loop, max

I need to find the max in the one column for the starting 300 rows for 11 times and then the max in next 220 rows, and then continue this pattern (11 times find max in 300 rows and one time in 220 rows)? Will a 'IF' or 'WHILE' should be used?

Comment: Do you want to use a macro to calculate?

Comment: I can use macro, but i am not that acquainted with macro

Comment: You can 't use a while loop in a formula.  You could adapt the Scott's answer to your last question by dragging (autofilling) down 12 rows and then change the last 12th row to 220 instead of 300.  Then if you want to continue for another 12, highlight all 12 cells and autofill down as far as you like and it should repleat the pattern.

Comment: yes, but I have like almost 500,000 rows of data, and I would have to repeat that. That's why I was thinking if a while or if loop might help

Comment: once you have the first set of 12 then you only have to highlight and drag/autofill down and you will have around 1800 rows of results.  It will take longer to write and maintain a macro.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a best way to write codes, it depends on what you like better and the time to execute you are looking for.

I would either use While or For.

Pseudo-code for While:

```
offset = first cell
int j = 0

While (1){

//First 300
int i = 0
While i <> 12{
offset = range (offset + 299)
Cell[j] = Max offset
i = i+1 }

//next 220
offset = offset + 1
offset = range(offset + 219)
Cell[j+1] = Max offset
j = j + 1
offset = offset + 1
}
```